# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' need to conver list of map as map

Tags: list, flutter, dart

the result I got as **List**

```
[{name: john, voted: [{5fhh54522b5: 8}, {2cg128gsc4541: 822}]}, {name: Donald, voted: [{8br55rj25ns3j: 822}, {jfej4v85552: 1}]}, {name: Abraham, voted: []}, {name: Colly, voted: []}]
```

need to convert this data as below map as.....**Map<dynamic,dynamic>**

```
{name: john, voted: [{5fhh54522b5: 8}, {2cg128gsc4541: 822}]}, {name: Donald, voted: [{8br55rj25ns3j: 822}, {jfej4v85552: 1}]}, {name: Abraham, voted: []}, {name: Colly, voted: []}
```

Comment: The data you got is already a list of maps, what you want. You need to explain what you exactly want to do with it. Because it's already in the format you wanted.

Comment: the result which I got in List<dynamic>
, Now I needs to convert it as Map<dynamic,dynamic>,
can you help me pls

Comment: The data you got here actually is List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>. I think you can relate now.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2019imesh/60e0339eb78f0985f6bc6d1095a61a6d can you pls copy the code on  https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ & refer the error pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your gist, I modified the code as follows

```
void main() {
  
  var dataList = jsonString;
  
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
  
  dataList.forEach((item) {
    if(item["voted"] != null) {
      (item["voted"] as List).forEach((voteItem) {
        if(voteItem != null) {
          (voteItem as Map).forEach((key, val){
            data[key] = val;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  print(data);
  //this what I need as reult 
  // {
  // 60e6956078fb6f42da: 1, 
  // 60e6956020d8bf42db: 5, 
  // 120d8bf42dffsww66: 1,
  // jd58466daa4dw2: 20,
  // gg4c577x6ad8ds6a: 6
  // }
}

const jsonString = [
    {
      "voted": [
        {
          "60e6956078fb6f42da": "1"
        },
        {
          "60e6956020d8bf42db": "5"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42dd",
      "name": "donald"
    },
    {
      "voted": [
        {
          "120d8bf42dffsww66": "1"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42de",
      "name": "barrack"
    },
    {
      "voted": [
        {
          "jd58466daa4dw2": "20"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42df",
      "name": "malan"
    },
    {
      "voted": [
        {
          "gg4c577x6ad8ds6a": "6"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42e0",
      "name": "kuma"
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Thank you.....this works for me........Highly appreciated.......Accepted and upvoted

Comment: I am new to the community....I got the error like................Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: 3/15 - unlock voting.......this is my leaderboard data.......will have 12 to unlock the voting

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is map

`{name: john, voted: [{5fhh54522b5: 8}, {2cg128gsc4541: 822}]}, {name: Donald, voted: [{8br55rj25ns3j: 822}, {jfej4v85552: 1}]}, {name: Abraham, voted: []}, {name: Colly, voted: []}`

they are multiple maps, not single map.

you can use list.asMap() function to convert list of any to map,

---

HI, i tried in dart pad, i can see that it is not valid json,
you have to convert it like  this, after that it you will be able to parse the json string easily

`voted :[ { id : '5fhh54522b5', count : '8'}, ]`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2019imesh/60e0339eb78f0985f6bc6d1095a61a6d can you pls copy the code on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ & refer the error pls